# Java - Change IconImage in JLabel created with JScrollPane

Tags: java

Probably a stupid question. My apologies if so. I couldn't find what I needed with google searches, but probably because I'm not really sure how to word what I need.

I have this line of code:

```
JScrollPane scrlPane = new JScrollPane(new JLabel(imgIcon));
```

This does exactly what I need it to do. However, I'm not sure how to change the image in the imgIcon after it's created with this method.

Again, I apologize if this is a stupid question. I've tried to create a separate JLabel outside of this method and add it to the JScrollPane, but for some reason, it draws a gray box over the image. I know it's drawing the image, because I can see 1 pixel of the image loaded around the edge of the gray box.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to keep a reference to your `JLabel` object, and to to use its `setIcon(Icon icon)` method to change it to your new `ImageIcon` object.

Or you can do somehting like this.

```
JViewport viewport = scrollPane.getViewport(); 
JLabel label = (JLabel)viewport.getView(); 
if (label != null) {
   label.setIcon(newImgIcon);
}
```